# How to SELECT TO_CHAR with list {11:00:00,12:00:00}

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, types, datetime-format

I have this table:

```
postgres::DATABASE=> SELECT * FROM db;
       timeList     |   time   
---------+------------+---------------------
{11:00:00,12:00:00} | 11:22:33
{19:00:00}          | 12:12:33
```

I need to select `timeList` values without seconds. But receive this error:

```
postgres::DATABASE=> SELECT TO_CHAR(timeList, 'HH24:MI') timeList FROM db;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "timeList"
LINE 1: SELECT TO_CHAR(time, 'HH24:MI') timeList FROM db;
                                        ^
```

Command to select single value works as expected:

```
postgres::DATABASE=> SELECT TO_CHAR(time, 'HH24:MI') time FROM db;
 time  
-------
 11:22
 12:12
```

Comment: The exact column specification (`CREATE TABLE` script? is it `time[]`?) and the version of Postgres would be instrumental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick and dirty

Assuming the column `"timeList"` is of type **`time[]`**, there is a quick and dirty way. Casting to **`varchar(5)[]`** truncates the string representation of the time so that only HH24:MI remains.

```sql
test=> SELECT '{12:12, 1:1:1.123456, 23:59:59.999999}'::time[]::varchar(5)[];
       varchar       
---------------------
 {12:12,01:01,23:59}
(1 row)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=95440ae86bf505223fcc92773f0c2a65)*

It even represents NULL and empty array properly out of the box. Pretty clean for "quick'n'dirty".

Of course, it depends on implementation details of the text representation of `time` values. But it works with any possible setting I am aware of, and I don't see it changing any time soon. Related:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT

#### Slow and sure

To format the output any way you want, there is always the slow and sure way that Laurenz provided: unnest, format, aggregate back. But it's typically faster to aggregate back right away with an ARRAY constructor in the `LATERAL` subquery. This is also guaranteed to keep original order of array elements without keeping track with `WITH ORDINALITY`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   db, LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT to_char(unnest(db.timelist), 'HH24:MI'))
   ) x(times_formatted);
```

Plus, the aggregation the subquery always produces a row, so it will not eliminate rows with NULL or empty array (`{}`) silently in the main table (like Laurenz' query does).

The implicit `CROSS JOIN` still has a side effect: it converts `NULL` to an empty array (`{}`).
Can be avoided properly with a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   db
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT to_char(unnest(db.timelist), 'HH24:MI'))
   ) x(times_formatted) ON db.timelist IS NOT NULL;
```

Consider the demo in the fiddle.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=95440ae86bf505223fcc92773f0c2a65)*

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)
- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167217/3684)
- [Preserve order of array elements after join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/119702/3684)

Answer (score 0):

Because of your denormalized data model, you have to use `unnest` and `array_agg`:

```
SELECT array_agg(to_char(tl.tle, 'HH24:MI') ORDER BY tl.n),
       to_char(db.time, 'HH24:MI')
FROM db
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(db.timelist) WITH ORDINALITY AS tl(tle, n)
GROUP BY db;
```

Comment: Be aware that the `CROSS JOIN` eliminates rows with NULL or empty array. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=95440ae86bf505223fcc92773f0c2a65